# Reading enter key in a loop in C

Tags: c

How can I read the enter key in a loop multiple times?

I've tried the following with no result.

```
char c;
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    c = getchar ();
    fflushstdin ();
    if (c == '\n'){
        //do something
    }
}
```

And fflushstdin:

```
void fflushstdin (){
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc (stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
}
```

If I read any other character instead of enter key it works perfect, but with enter key In some iterations I have to press the enter 2 times.

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm executing the program through putty on windows and the program is running on a virtualized linux mint on virtual box.

Comment: getch() reads a key hit without waiting for you to press enter.
getchar() requires you to hit enter, so you end up hitting twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you call fflushstdin()? If fgetc() returns something different from \n, that character is completely dropped.

This should work:

```
char prev = 0;

while(1)
{
    char c = getchar();

    if(c == '\n' && prev == c)
    {
        // double return pressed!
        break;
    }

    prev = c; 
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but this solution is the correct O.o. Thanks! It solves the double enter key press.

Comment: In regex expression, your solution above accepts '\n.*\n' whereas this accepts '\n\n'

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (ch == 13) {
  //do something
}
```

ASCII value of enter is 13, sometimes \n won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with:

```
char c;
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    c = getchar ();
    fflushstdin ();
    if (c == 13){
        //do something
    }
}
```

since `13` is ASCII code for `Enter` key.

Comment: Why not using '\r' instead? It is the same but much more readable.

Comment: Still not working with 10 and 13. 10 produces the same result as \n and with 13 it simply does not execute the if condition.

Comment: try as: c = getch(); and then if (c == 13) { ... }

Comment: @mru `'\r'` is no more readable than `13` IMO, `#define ENTER_KEY 13` (or `#define ENTER_KEY '\r'`, if you like) is. Code style is not relevant to this question though.

Comment: @Panther24 getch() in non-standard C function, and you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

You always executing `getchar` twice (even when there is no need for that). Try limiting calls to `fflushstdin`:

```
char c;
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    c = getchar ();
    if ((c != EOF) && (c != '\n')) fflushstdin ();
    if (c == '\n'){
        //do something
    }
}
```