# C prompt user to press enter key and exit after one press

Tags: c, input

I have a C program and as part of it I want to prompt the user to "press enter to continue" but I keep running into having to press the enter key twice. I want to detect a single enter key press. I saw this post [Reading enter key in a loop in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144977/reading-enter-key-in-a-loop-in-c) and tried

```
char prev = 0;

while(1)
{
    printf("Press enter to continue \n");
    char c = getchar();

    if(c == '\n' && prev == c)
    {
        break;
    }

    prev = c;
}
```

but that didn't work for me, still have to press enter twice, and prints the prompt twice. So then I just tried

```
while (1) {
    printf("press enter to continue \n");
    char prompt;
    prompt = getchar();
    if(prompt == 0x0A){
        break;
    }
}
```

but that still makes me press the enter key twice before moving on, though I only get the prompt once, so that is moving in the right direction. Any advice on a better approach?

Comment: The top one doesn't work because `c != '\n'` (it works on the second Enter because of the `prev == c`. But the second example [works fine for me](https://repl.it/repls/UnfinishedComplicatedAssembler) on the first Enter press, so I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: The first code fragment demands two consecutive newline characters — if you only want to enter one, don't use that code (or remove the `prev` variable from it).  Both fragments have problems if the user indicates EOF (typing control-D on a typical Unix system, control-Z on a Windows system).  Using `0x0A` instead of `'\n'` is not good style, for all that it works on most systems you're likely to encounter (but definitely not on all system you could encounter).  Also, both fragments store the `int` value returned by `getchar()` into a `char`; that's wrong.

Comment: First, `getchar()` returns a `int`, not a `char`

Comment: This is somewhat of an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because much will depend on what input you are taking. If you are reading multi-character input (e.g. names, sentences, etc..), you are not going to be reading input and storing each character in a variable by itself. In that case, just use `fgets` and check the first character by dereferencing the buffer filled and comparing against `'\n'` (the `EOF` case is handled by `fgets` returning `NULL`)

Comment: @user3629249 yes. Perhaps It is better to say that "returns the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int "

Comment: The problem is due the **previous** un-posted input.  A [mcve] to demo and then solve the problem is best.

Comment: @manoliar, the function `getchar()` actually returns an `int, not some unsigned char cast to an `int`.   This is very clear when working with EOF

Comment: @user3629249 there a lot of documentation about that "cast to an int" for getchar(). for example: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html Also IBM says that "The getc() and getchar() functions return the character read. A return value of EOF indicates ......" . This is a promotion to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
while (1) {
    printf("press enter to continue \n");
    char prompt;
    prompt = getchar();
    if(prompt == 0x0A){
        break;
    }
}
```

You might try (after emptying `stdin`

```
do
{
    printf("press enter to continue \n");
    int prompt = getchar();
} while( prompt != '\n' && prompt != EOF );
```

Comment: For the person who tried to edit my answer.  1) the 'scope' of variables should be limited as much as possible.  moving the declaration of 'prompt' to before the do...while loop makes the 'scope' of the variable unnecessarily large, when, in general, it should be limited to the do...while loop. 2) using a space inside parens and around C operators goes a long way toward readability of the code (the compiler doesn't care)

Comment: Doesn't compile for me, errors at the `while` line: `error: ‘prompt’ undeclared (first use in this function)`; See my answer if you want to limit the scope :)

Answer (score 1):

### You can also try this

```
char ch;
//infinite loop
while(1)
{
printf("Enter any character: ");
//read a single character
ch=fgetc(stdin);
if(ch==0x0A)
{
printf("ENTER KEY is pressed.\n");
break;
}
ch=getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int prompt = 0; prompt != '\n' && prompt != EOF; prompt = getchar())
        printf("press enter to continue \n");
}
```